# How to make the Uploader Plugin behavior way working

Tags: model-view-controller, plugins, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to working with the [Uploader](http://milesj.me/blog/read/changelog-uploader-3.6) Plugin to create a structure where a `User` Model can upload it's avatar with the `Avatar` Model, I've read the instructions several times but when I try to `$this->Uploader->upload('Avatar.filename')` I get no validation errors but the upload method fails.

Here is how I've written the `User` Model

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    public $hasOne = array(
        'Profile' => array(
            'className' => 'Profile',
            'conditions' => '',
            'dependent' => true,
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associatedKey' => 'user_id'
        ),
        'Avatar' => array (
            'className' => 'Avatar',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
    public $validate = array(...);
    // other stuff not relevant here...
?>
```

Here is the `Avatar` Model

```
<?php
class Avatar extends AppModel {
public $name = 'Avatar';
public $actsAs = array (
    'Uploader.Attachment' => array (
        'Avatar.filename' => array(
            'name'      => 'setNameAsImgId',    // Name of the function to use to format filenames
            'baseDir'   => '',                  // See UploaderComponent::$baseDir
            'uploadDir' => 'files/avatars/',    // See UploaderComponent::$uploadDir
            'dbColumn'  => 'filename',          // The database column name to save the path to
            'importFrom'    => '',              // Path or URL to import file
            'defaultPath'   => '',              // Default file path if no upload present
            'maxNameLength' => 500,             // Max file name length
            'overwrite' => true,                // Overwrite file with same name if it exists
            'stopSave'  => true,                // Stop the model save() if upload fails
            'allowEmpty'    => true,            // Allow an empty file upload to continue
            'transforms'    => array (
                array('method' => 'resize', 'width' => 128, 'height' => 128, 'dbColumn' => 'name')
            )       // What transformations to do on images: scale, resize, ete
        )
    ),
    'Uploader.FileValidation' => array (
        'Avatar.filename' => array (
            'maxWidth'  => array (
                'value' => 512,
                'error' => 'maxWidth error'
            ),
            'maxHeight' => array (
                'value' => 512,
                'error' => 'maxWidth error'
            ),
            'extension' => array (
                'value' =>  array('gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'),
                'error' => 'extension error'
            ),
            'filesize'  => array (
                'value' => 5242880,
                'error' => 'filesize error'
            )
        )
    )
);

public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className'     => 'User',
        'foreignKey'    => 'user_id',
        'conditions'    => '',
        'order'         => ''
    )
);

public function setNameAsImgId ($name, $field, $file) {
    /**
    * Format the filename a specific way before uploading and attaching.
    * 
    * @access public
    * @param string $name   - The current filename without extension
    * @param string $field  - The form field name
    * @param array $file    - The $_FILES data
    * @return string
    */
    // devo ricavare l'id dell'immagine appena creata per rinominare il file
    return $name;
}
}
?>
```

This is the `UsersController` for `edit` method

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeEmail','Network/Email');
CakePlugin::load('Uploader');
App::import('Vendor', 'Uploader.Uploader');

class UsersController extends AppController {
public $name = 'Users';

public function edit ($id) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException ('Nessuna corrispondenza trovata per questo utente');
    }
    if (!$id) {
        $this->set('flash_element','error');
        $this->Session->setFlash ('Utente non valido');
    }
    $this->User->recursive = 1;
    $this->set('user', $this->User->read());

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->id = $this->request->data['User']['id'];
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            $this->set('flash_element','warning');
            $this->Session->setFlash('Nessun utente trovato con questa corrispondenza');
    }
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->request->data['Profile']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;

        $conditions = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Profile.id' => $this->request->data['Profile']['id']
            )
        );

        if ($this->User->Profile->save($this->request->data, $conditions)) {

            if (!empty($this->request->data['Avatar']['filename'])) {

                $this->request->data['Avatar']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;
                if ($this->User->Avatar->save($this->request->data)) {

                    $avatar = $this->User->Avatar->find('first', array(
                        'conditions' => array('Avatar.user_id' => $this->User->id)
                    ));
                    $ext = Uploader::ext($this->request->data['Avatar']['filename']);
                    $filename = $avatar['Avatar']['id'].'.'.$ext;


                if ($this->User->Avatar->save('Avatar.filename')) {
                    $this->set('flash_element','done');
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Avatar changed successfully');
                    debug('saved successfully');
                } else {
                    debug('not saved');
                    $this->set('flash_element','warning');
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Avatar not saved on the server');
                }

                } else {
                        $this->Session->write('flash_element','error');
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Avatar data not saved on the server');
                        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->Session->write('flash_element','done');
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Data successfully saved, avatar not changed');
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
                }
        } else {
                $this->set('flash_element','error');
                $this->Session->setFlash('Error on saving Profile data to the server');
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->write('flash_element','error');
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error on saving User data to the server');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

And in the `view` file I have this

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array ('class' => 'form'));
echo $this->Form->input('User.id', array ('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=> $user['User']['id'],'label'=> false, 'id' => 'id'));
echo $this->Form->input('User.username', array ('label'=> false, 'value' => $user['User']['username'], 'id' => 'username', 'after' => '<div class="message">Message for username field'));
echo $this->Form->input('User.email', array ('label'=> false, 'value' => $user['User']['email'], 'id' => 'email', 'after' => '<div class="message">Message for email field</div>'));
echo $this->Form->input('UserOptions.id', array ('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=> $user['UserOptions']['id'],'label'=> false, 'id' => 'UserOptions.id'));
$attributes = array ('value' => $user['UserOptions']['avatar_type'], 'empty' => false);
$options = array('0' => 'This site', '1' => 'Gravatar');
echo $this->Form->select('UserOptions.avatar_type', $options, $attributes);
/* avatar code */
echo $this->Form->input('Avatar.id', array ('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=> $user['Avatar']['id'],'label'=> false, 'id' => 'Avatar.id'));
echo $this->Form->input('Avatar.filename', array('type' => 'file'));
/* end avatar code */
echo $this->Form->input('Profile.city', array ('label'=> false, 'value' => defaultValue ('City', $user['Profile']['city']), 'id' => 'city', 'after' => '<div class="message">Message for city field</div>'));
echo $this->Form->input('Profile.country', array ('label'=> false, 'value' => defaultValue('',$user['Profile']['country']), 'id' => 'country', 'after' => '<div class="message">Message for country field</div>'));
echo $this->Form->input('Profile.url', array ('label'=> false, 'value' => defaultValue('http://', $user['Profile']['url']), 'id' => 'url', 'after' => '<div class="message">Message for url field</div>'));
echo $this->Form->input('Profile.description', array ('label'=> false, 'value' => defaultValue('Description',$user['Profile']['description']), 'id' => 'description', 'after' => '<div class="message">Message for description field</div>'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Modifica', array('id'=>'edit'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

In the Controller, every part of the data is `saved` until I reach `$this->Uploader->upload('Avatar.filename', array('overwrite' => true, 'name' => $filename))` where I get a generic error.

This Plugin seems to be the best way to do it without write tons of code, but I'm not sure how to use it.
I'm not sure what's wrong with the code, can You help me to solve the problem?

Comment: What version of CakePHP and Uploader do you use? Uploader 2.8 is for CakePHP 1.3 and Uploader 3.x is for CakePHP 2.0. Architecture of Uploader has changed, so you should take care to match them and initialize Uploader differently. See http://milesj.me/blog/read/upgrading-uploader-2.8-3

Comment: And please never write 'generic error' :) Exact error message tells a lot.

Comment: @GregSmirnov I'm using `CakePHP 2.1.3` and `Uploader 3.6`, my problem is exactly in the `generic error`, the database data is saved, but the file is not uploaded to the folder without return any error, I thought it was a `folder permission` problem but it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problems, I forgot two things:

In the `view` page I've forgot `'type' => 'file'`

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array ('class' => 'form', 'type' => 'file'));
?>
```

I was used to work with 1.3 version so the `app/Config/bootstrap.php` configuration was missing:

```
<?php
CakePlugin::load('Uploader');
?>
```

Now it works!